# How to get "for or foreach" looping values on return statement as the echo statement get

Tags: php, html, loops

I have this code

```php
$list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
  echo $list[$i]; //result : onetwo

$res = ['data' => [
  ['message' => "The number is $list[$i]"]
]];
return $res;
//result
//   {
//     "data": [
//         {
//             "message": "The number is three"
//         }
//     ]
// }
```

How to get all the $list's values so the result is:
(actually $list's values is data from database).

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "message": "The number is one two three"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `implode` would do it. Don't use `echo`. either change `echo $list[$i];` to `$values .= $list[$i];` and define `$values` as empty string to start, or use `implode`.

Comment: `'message' => 'The number is ' . implode(' ', $list)`

Comment: You also likely could just `group_concat` the value at DB level then not need to rejoin.